# Small Web App, Adding repeater grid items dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, subsonic, repeater

```
private void BindGridToppings()
    {

    }
```

here's the gridview from the asp page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableModelValidation="true" OnRowDataBound="Pizzas_RowBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ID="btnEditPizza" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' onClick="Pizzas_RowEditing" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/del.png" ID="btnDeletePizza" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' OnClick="Pizzas_RowDeleting" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField  DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pizza ID" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Crust">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCrust" runat="server" Text='<%#GetNameByLookUpID(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Crust").ToString()) %>'>            </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cheese">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCheese" runat="server" Text='<%#GetNameByLookUpID(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem ,"Cheese").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="Cost" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Toppings">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" Runat="server">                            
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>                
</asp:GridView>
```

SQL and SubSonic are used as the backend, I only started programming with a database two weeks ago. So accessing it is still new to me.

Either my DB.Where...... call was incorrectly formatted in the BindGridToppings function as the complimer told me. Or A subsonic query is not a class that can be interated, as my compiler told me when I tried a foreach loop and .items.add

Any advice on how to bind this repeater would be lovely.

Thanks, Macaire Bell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution.

```
    protected void Pizzas_RowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int pizzaID = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblID")).Text);
            BulletedList bltTopping = ((BulletedList)e.Row.FindControl("bltTopping"));
            ToppingsCollection toppings = ToppingsMembers.RetriveByPizzaID(pizzaID);
            bltTopping.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Toppings topping in toppings)
            {
            bltTopping.Items.Add(new ListItem(GetNameByLookUpID(topping.ToppingID.ToString())));
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Toppings">
                <ItemTemplate>                
                    <asp:BulletedList ID="bltTopping" Runat="server">                            
                    </asp:BulletedList>
                </ItemTemplate>                
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

in the front

Thank you for you're help though it led me to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow what you're saying here...

> Either my DB.Where...... call was incorrectly formatted in the BindGridToppings function as the complimer told me. Or A subsonic query is not a class that can be interated, as my compiler told me when I tried a foreach loop and .items.add

I see no call to `BindGridToppings()`? Are you trying to resolve those compiler errors (we need a little more information on those if so), or get the right binding technique for a Repeater inside a GridView?

If your issue is how to resolve binding a Repeater inside a GridView, try this.

ASPX like this:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Foo1" DataField="Foo1" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FooFive">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FooFive") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> foo1Objects = new List<object>();
        foo1Objects.Add(new { Foo1 = "Hello" });
        foo1Objects.Add(new { Foo1 = "World" });

        GridView1.DataSource = foo1Objects;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rep1 = e.Row.FindControl("Repeater1") as Repeater;
        if (rep1 != null)
        {
            List<object> fooFiveObjects = new List<object>();
            fooFiveObjects.Add(new { FooFive = "Apple" });
            fooFiveObjects.Add(new { FooFive = "Orange" });
            fooFiveObjects.Add(new { FooFive = "Banana" });

            rep1.DataSource = fooFiveObjects;
            rep1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I would expect your data-retrieval and GridView1 data binding to work a little differently, but the key is handling the `GridView1_RowDataBound` event to bind the repeater.